# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" v-for loop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an input text inside two v-for loops.

```
  <div>
       <div v-for="(property, propIndex) in properties" :key="propIndex">
           {{ property.plot_name }}
          <div v-for="(house_type, typeIndex) in property.house_type.data" :key="typeIndex">
              {{ house_type.type }}<br>
              <input type="text" v-model="form[propIndex][typeIndex]">Rent<br>
              
          </div>
          <br>
       </div>
    </div>
```

When I use identify the v-model with only one index as follows:

```
<input type="text" v-model="form[propIndex]">Rent<br>
```

or

```
<input type="text" v-model="form[typeIndex]">Rent<br>
```

I do not get an error. But when I identify the v-model using two indexes

```
 <input type="text" v-model="form[propIndex][typeIndex]">Rent<br>
```

then I get the error
`Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

What could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form object in data is just an empty object, and that's fine, if a value is undefined, then you just get undefined. But then you start to iterate over some children of the undefined (the typeIndex being 0 doesn't exist on undefined propIndex).

It's hard to say what's the best solution without seeing your data and understanding desired effect, but I guess it's safe to say that populating your form object in the data with all possible values od propIndex would fix your problem.

```
data () {
  return  {
    form: [
      {}, {}, {}, {}, {} // as many as the possible propIndex values you expect
    ]
  } 
}
```

Comment: This works. Is it possible to set the propIndex values programatically. I'm getting the number of properties from the database. Is it possible that if I have 3 properties, I can have: form: [
      {}, {}, {}
    ] and if I have four I can have  form: [
      {}, {}, {}, {}
    ]

Comment: I think it should be possible in the `created()` hook of the component. Or in the data itself. Like: `form: new Array(3).fill({})`